# MySql - How to join two tables, but with not exact values but similar

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
View1
Columns:
id int(11) AI PK 
pcode varchar(255) 
ref1 varchar(255) 
des varchar(255)

Table1
Columns:
id int(11) 
pcode varchar(255) 
brand varchar(255) 
description varchar(255) 
size varchar(255) 
barcode varchar(255)
```

My main concentration point is the `des` and `description`

This is an example of what values are in the two columns for two different table.

```
   View1
Column:   des
des
Pens - (MP)
Paper (5kg)
Mouse

  Table1
Column :   description
Pens MP
Pens
Paper 5kg
Mouse
```

As you probably see there is some similarity but they're written differently.

As an example `view1` has a value of `Pens - (MP)` and `table1` has a value of `Pens MP` without the `-` and another value `Pens`. The correct join would be `Pens MP` as they are the closest match.

How could I possible join the two tables together depending on their similarity.

I'm not sure whether there is a built in function, or some what query needs to be carefully coded. Or I might need to look a a different software with a different language?

Comment: You would fix your data.  Trying to join on such strings is just a path to frustration.  You need to identify each row and set up proper foreign key relationships.

Comment: I agree with you on that one, will need to have a good think about the linking in the data and see where I can match the two together not using description. But about my post, I was curious if this is still possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am just selecting a subset of the columns for demo purposes:

```
SELECT View1.id as id1,
       des,
       Table1.id as id2,
       description
FROM View1 INNER JOIN Table1
WHERE SOUNDEX(des) = SOUNDEX(description)
;
```

The above will match descriptions that only vary by non-alphabetic characters, such as spaces, parentheses, hyphens, etc.

Comment: how did you came across to this in the first place haha? in other words, where did you learn it

Comment: I'm so old who can remember? Seriously, the Soundex algorithm has been around for about 100 years and is a phonetic algorithm for converting words into numbers based on their sounds so that similar sounding words convert to the same number. It's clearly an algorithm for matching words that differ in only minor spelling variations. I only suggested it because in the few examples shown there were perfect matches if you ignore non-alphabetic characters. If that's not the case, Soundex will not suffice, but I don't know then what will.

Comment: @Eduard . . . Sound is probably a really poor choice for this.  It was designed by the US Census Bureau to match last names.  It has tons of limitations for actually doing a match -- when it was devised, a human was always going to review the results anyway.

Comment: @Gordon, regardless of what it was designed for, if you need to compare two strings that differ in only in non-alphabetic characters, which seems to be the case here, it does the job because the algorithm ignores those characters. If two strings are dissimilar for other reasons, then this is a much bigger problem.